# Does Revolution Slider work on Wordpress mulitsite?

Tags: multisite, revolution-slider

Does Revolution Slider work on Wordpress mulit-site?

-Chad

Answer (score 0):

Find function `mfn_get_sliders` in `functions/meta-functions.php` and replace

```
$table_name = $wpdb->base_prefix . "revslider_sliders";
```

with:

```
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "revslider_sliders";
```

After this sliders will show properly under multi-site installations.